# How to call a two functions with unequal arguments using same function call?

Tags: python

I have two definitions say,

file x.py:

```
class x:

    def p(self, a, b) :
        # ...
```

file y.py:

```
class y:

    def p(self, a, b, c) :
        # [...]
```

Now I am calling these functions from another file. Command line inputs having the file names (in this case x and y) are passed in `cust` variable.

file z.py:

```
from x import  *
from y import  *

class z:

    cust.p(a, b, c)
```

x (or y) is being passed as the command line inputs to file z.py.
`cust` is the class variable of class z.

Now when `cust = x` object I get an error: `takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`.

But when `cust = y` object it works fine.

How do i eliminate this error?

I do not want to modify the function definition in x.py and y.py files as there are many files.

How do i modify the code so that both the functions are called from the same function call **without modifying** the function definition?

Comment: Your code isn't properly formatted- indent each line to make a code block.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do at all. Is cust a variable of class x or class y? And what do you mean call both functions from the same function call? One function call will never call two functions (unless, say, it calls another function which calls both).

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information. I have edited the question.

Comment: See for example this: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? what are the actual names of things? What do you want to happen to `c` in the case that `cust` is an `x` object? Why is it OK to treat things this way?

Comment: Update the function definition. 'Many files' shouldn't be a problem, you can do a query/repleace over multiple files in almost any decent text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monkeypatch.

```
x.p = lambda self, a, b, c=None: x.p(self, a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your methods to make the third parameter optional in both...

```
class x:
  def p(a, b, c=None):
    """ c will be ignored. """
    print a, b


class y:
  def p(a, b, c=1234):
    """ c will be used, with a default of 1234. """
    print a, b, c

x().p(1, 2)
x().p(1, 2, 123)
y().p(1, 2)
y().p(1, 2, 123)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not wanted to change the function definition like making the variable "c=None".

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the code and your specifications (which, honestly, are not very clear), you want to call the functions from both files at the same time, and you have this variable called `cust` through which you call them as methods.

Until you specify what `cust` is, there is not much I can do to help. I also am unsure of how it is both of classes `x` and `y` simultaneously. This *might* be what you want:

```
#file x.py
class x:
    def p(self, a, b):
        ...

#file y.py
class y:
    def p(self, a, b, c):
        ...

#file z.py
from x import *
from y import *
my_x = x()
my_y = y()
a = ...
b = ...
my_x.p(a, b)
my_y.p(a, b, c)
```

I would like you to be more specific as to what you want so I can help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wanted to call both the functions with one function call. To explain it properly i wanted to do x.p = lambda self, a, b, c=None: x.p(self, a, b)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty answer is:

```
try:
   cust.p(a,b,c)
except TypeError:
   cust.p(a,b)
```

Disclaimer: there are numerous problems with how the original problem has been defined, so the approach doesn't seem to make anything worse.

Comment: I was thinking of this but is there any other better way of doing it?.

Comment: The better way of doing it is to change the function definitions. I'm not sure what you mean by "I do not want to modify the function definition in x.py and y.py files as there are many files"- do you mean that that code is duplicated so it would have to be changed in multiple places? In that case, you have more serious problems than this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the function being called to use `*args` or `**kwargs`, then you have to add special cases to see what class the object is:

```
if isinstance(cust, x):
    cust.p(a, b)
elif isinstance(cust, y):
    cust.p(a, b, c)
```

See [this link](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) for more information about the `isinstance` function.